# BlackBerry webworks : window size (Window height) returning incorrect value in blackberry simulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry-webworks

```
{
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();
}
```

I m printing the winH and winW its giving incorrect values in the Blackberry simulator and on the real device also (BB 9800)

Solution :

In blackberry widgets, Getting window width and height using jquery is giving incorrect values..The solution is 
{ `var winH = screen.height; var winW = screen.width;` }

Comment: In blackberry widgets, Getting window width and height using jquery is giving incorrect values..The solution is { var winH = screen.height;  var winW = screen.width; }

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem and here is my solution. Its related with the device pixel ratio. Thats is, in a pc the relation between pixels in css and pixels in screen is 1:1

However in some devices this ratio changes to 1:2.24 or different values

My solution was:

```
var winW = screen.width*window.devicePixelRatio;
var winH = screen.height*window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and what i used that returned correct values is

```
var widthh = window.innerWidth;
var heightt = window.innerHeight
```